# DTrace to trap any chmod applied to certain files

Tags: osx, monitoring, system-calls, dtrace

Underneath the Mac OS X directory `/audit` I have certain files which users can access and `chmod` to their liking.

I need to audit any `chmod` done on any files by recording the time, user and file being `chmod`, especially the latter.

I can `dtrace -n 'syscall::chmod:entry'` and detect the events, how do I read the first argument to `chmod`?

`man 2 chmod` tells me the path is in the first argument:

```
chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

but how can I read `args[0]`? I think I am doing this the wrong way around.. perhaps entry doesn't correspond to the actual syscall?

If I have a probe I can monitor, how can I check which parameters it offers for access and what types they are? I am assuming some pointers will need to be dereferenced based on their data layout..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument's in `arg0`, but that's the caller's userspace address rather than the actual string. You need to wrap it with a `copyinstr()` as well:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::chmod:entry { printf("%d %s", uid, copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

Comment: Can I also substitute arg0 with something else I prefer? Before or after the line executes? Can I prevent execution of the line altogether?

Comment: I don't think you can substitute arg0. The only way I can see to prevent execution of the syscall altogether would be to use the [destructive action](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18752_01/html/817-6223/chp-actsub-4.html) raise(9) which would kill the process trying to do the chmod.

Comment: Instead of killing the "offender" one could temporarily substitute the filename with an empty string - in the `:entry` probe, use `copyin()` to remember the first byte of the name (into `self->t`, for example), then `copyout()` to overwrite it with `\0`, and in the `:return` probe restore the previous byte. It's not 100% safe to do that (again, destructive actions required) - if the offending process is multithreaded though, this can race if the memory where the filename is stored is used/accessed concurrently by multiple threads.